# How to create a tooltip in a TeeChart asp.net chart

Tags: tooltip, teechart

I am using a TeeChart line graph in an asp.net web application.

I would like to show a tooltip when the mouse is hovered over a point in the graph.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeeChart .NET WebCharts are basically created server-side, exported to an image that is sent to the client's browser. Of course, this technique limits the interactivity, but WebCharts still support some of this interactivity as shown in the live demo here:
http://www.steema.net/TeeChartForNET/index.aspx

Concretelly, the Mouseover feature can be explored in the examples under "Interacting with Charts\Mouseover Hints"

Steema Support Team.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up needing something more sophisticated so after the map was rendered by the chart i played around with JS to get the exact effect i wanted.